# Javascript: Fetch promise failed after some waiting time on page

Tags: javascript, fetch, es6-promise

I am trying a fetch call using promise which is called on **input** event.
The API works properly at the beginning and returns proper response.
The problem is when I wait for sometime on the page and then call the API back by using same input event on text box. It throws **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch** error.

Below is the action to call the API

```
document.getElementById('search-autocomplete-list').addEventListener('input', function() {
    fetch(autoUrl, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    })
    .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
    })
});
```

The above code works but only failed if user waits for some time(1 minute or more) on the page and again start adding input to the text box.

Please help me if I missing something in the fetch call header or any other issue. Thank you.

Comment: Can you try with `blur` instead of `input` and see if it happens? `blur` will trigger when an element loses focus

Comment: Chain `.catch(console.log)` after `.then` to see the error from promise

Comment: adding `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` in the **request header** suggests you're trying to *bypass* CORS ... `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` is a **response** header from a server which *allows* you to fetch that resource - if such a header is not present in the **response** then the server is telling you that you my not *borrow* its resources without **permission** to do so

Comment: @Trisma I am trying to get an autocomplete list after each input change. By using blur the functionality will change completely and I am also getting the error of promise so API is hitting but could not able to fetch reponse.

Comment: @darklightcode The error says "TypeError: Failed to fetch" in catch block using console

Comment: Try adding the 3rd parameter to .`addEventListener( event, callback, false )` to prevent bubbling. The way i see it, that request might get aborted somehow. Is that a "live-search-while-typing" ?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't caught in some sort of event loop issue? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: @darklightcode SOLVED: The issue was related to application protocol. The protocol was http and the API call url was https. Thank you so much for your replies.